# Kibana cannot draw the Histogram of the float values

Tags: kibana

Kibana cannot correctly draw a the Histogram of the float values.
The result of query to elasticsearch contains the field "Value" and the value is "88.23692".

I select "mean" in "Chart value" and put "Value" in "Value Field" on Panel Settings of the histogram.

However it looks like the histogram can't display the values correctly. Y-axis contains great numbers: sextillions.

Could anybody please tell me whether Kibana can deal with float numbers and if yes what is correct numbers format?

Answer (score 1):

Kibana 4 (currently in beta) supports this, based on the aggregations API rather than the deprecated facets API.

Answer (score 0):

Kibana histogram behavior is based upon time periods.You can plot a histogram (time vs values).You should be able to draw a histogram on some time field.Select "count" in "Chart Value" and time/date type value in "timefield".You should be able to see the histogram plotted.For drawing mean you can try with "Stats" panel where you will have formatting options (number,float etc).

Hope this helps!